# Mux, Multiplexer: Why not merge these two tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

I just saw [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/404339/how-does-the-circuit-design-of-a-42-mux-look-like) where the OP tagged the question as [mux](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mux) and [multiplexer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplexer).

Looking at the info for [mux](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mux), there's no information whatsoever.

[image]

---

With [multiplexer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplexer), this is different.

[image]

---

**Is there a reason why we need both of these tags if one is simply a shorthanded writing expression of the other?** Both tags do receive a fair amount of utilization.

Comment: What is a "multiplexer" anyway? Is it a 74HC digital mux, a RF multiplexer, an analog switch, something else? Seems fairly ambiguous to me. If you just say "mux" though, I will assume some 74HC standard digital IC.

Comment: @Lundin Well my point was these two tags are homogeneous. You can use these two expressions interchangeably (even for an RF multiplexer, you can say "mux" as well). I believe the action of implementing a multiplexer is either called muxing or multiplexing. **Overall, these two expressions can be used at the same time. I don't think the community will delete one or the other but rather combine both of them into a single tag.** So when a user tags a question as "mux", "multiplexer" will also show up under the same option.

Comment: @Lundin. I assume nothing by the term 'mux'. Sure there is analog and digital, but there is a huge gap in speed between a 74HCxx series and MC100EPxx ECL series, some of which work to 3 GHZ.

Comment: Isn't a mux and a multiplexer the same thing?

Comment: @iBug Precisely why I asked this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any point having both of them.

I've [proposed the tag synonym](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/multiplexer/synonyms) on the multiplexer page to have [mux](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mux) mapped to [multiplexer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplexer) as they are basically common terms for the same thing.

Comment: First time I ever notice this tag synonyms voting system. Providing a link was a good idea.

Comment: Muxing is also a synonym :) Unfortunately I don't have enough "rep" to vote on this.

Comment: @KingDuken Mux is now a synonym. I've not proposed muxing for now as there are no questions tagged with it. If that changes later, it can always be proposed.